# How to call a method from a different file using event bus

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in CreateEntryStepper.vue i have a button that i want that when pressed calls a function to activate in CreateEntryStepperImageUpload.vue

i know i have to use event busses but i really have no idea what i need to pass in and how to get them working

bus.js just has

```
import Vue from "vue";

export const bus = new Vue();
```

CreateEntryStepper.vue (not sure what to emit here)

```
import { bus } from "@/components/wizard/bus.js";
```

```
    async submitEntry() {

      this.$Progress.start();
      bus.$emit();
```

CreateEntryStepperImageUpload.vue (saveImage is the method i want to call)

```
import { bus } from "@/components/wizard/bus.js";
```

not sure where to put this

```
    bus.$on()
```

```
    async saveImage() {
```

Now what i need is what do i emit? and how can i make it so saveImage is called when that button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You emit the name of the event, which can be anything you want. For example: `bus.$emit('upload-image');`, and then you listen to this event and trigger your callback with:

```
bus.$on('upload-image', () => {
  saveImage
    .then(/* Do stuff */)
    .catch(/* Do stuff */);
});`
```

For more information on how custom events work, you can refer to the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html